# How to convert javascript object to python readable

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to parse below object from javascript post data into python using ast.literal_eval(obj) but ending up into below error

Error:

```
malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7fb484eb8070>
```

Object Value:

```
'[{"dose":"1","duration":"2","name":"Item1","code":"pharma2","usage":{"morning":true,"afternoon":false,"evening":false,"night":false,"sos":false}},{"dose":"1","duration":"4","name":"Item2","code":"pharma1","usage":{"morning":false,"afternoon":false,"evening":false,"night":true,"sos":false}}]'
```

Comment: `json.loads()`?

Comment: Hey, Thanks - Json.loads() worked.

Answer (score 0):

[demjson.decode()](https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson)

```
import demjson

jsObject = '{"dose":"1","duration":"2","name":"Item1","code":"pharma2","usage":{"morning":true,"afternoon":false,"evening":false,"night":false,"sos":false}},{"dose":"1","duration":"4","name":"Item2","code":"pharma1","usage":{"morning":false,"afternoon":false,"evening":false,"night":true,"sos":false}}'

pythonObject = demjson.decode(jsObject)
```

Comment: Why to introduce a new dependency if Python can decode it with the standard library?